# substr returns an empty string when string is less than start characters long in PHP 8

Tags: php, php-8

The [PHP docs for `substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) says:

> If string is less than start characters long, FALSE will be returned.

and gives the example

```php
$rest = substr("abcdef", 4, -4);  // returns false
```

Interestingly this seems to be not true starting with PHP 8.0.0rc1 as in newer versions the function returns an empty string instead:

https://3v4l.org/RPU1s

Is this a bug in PHP or an undocumented change (or am I misunderstanding something)?

Comment: What about rc4?

Comment: The fact that this behavior shows up in an rc tells me this may be a bug.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, you'd have to build it yourself as rc4 is not available on 3v4l just yet.

Comment: [This page](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/substr-out-of-bounds) describes the same thing, and labels it as a 'change', although I'm not sure what they're basing that on.

Comment: 3v4l shows that the same thing happens on the master branch, so I assume it didn't change in rc4

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6182 shows that this indeed seems to be intentional.

Comment: It's also mentioned in the [UPGRADING](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.0RC4/UPGRADING) docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this was an intentional change as mentioned in
https://php.watch/versions/8.0/substr-out-of-bounds

and implemented here:

https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6182